# 'Creating maven-archetype.quickstart' has encountered a problem

Tags: eclipse, maven

I was creating a new Maven project in Eclipse but I always encouter the following error:

> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.4 from any of the configured repositories.
>   Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4
>   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-archetype-quickstart-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from/to maven-archetype-quickstart-repo (h ttps://repo1.maven.org/maven2): repo1.maven.org
>   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-archetype-quickstart-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from/to maven-archetype-quickstart-repo (http s://repo1.maven.org/maven2): repo1.maven.org
>   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from htt ps://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from/to maven-archetype-quickstart-repo (htt ps://repo1.maven.org/maven2): repo1.maven.org
>   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from/to maven-archetype-quickstart-repo (htt ps://repo1.maven.org/maven2): repo1.maven.org

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html.

Comment: Looks like an network/firewall/proxy issue `Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.4 from ht tps://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, .`

Comment: yes I see it, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I just re-installed Eclipse. Now it works